# Force OData to interprete query as one entity

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have a API controller with the following method used to retrieve one specific object. The output is formatted in Json.

```
[Route("~/api/orders({key:int})", Name = "GetOrder")]
public IHttpActionResult GetOrder([FromODataUri] int key, ODataQueryOptions<Order> queryOptions)
```

It works as follows.

1. Build up a base query from Entity Framework named baseQuery
2. Apply the Odata filters to the base query using

   queryOptions.ApplyTo(baseQuery.OrderByDescending(f => f.Id)
                                               , querySettings);
3. Return the resulting IQueryable

The problem is that this results in a list containing one object (the one asked for). I would like to have it return the object itself rather then a list with the object.

I have tried adding FirstOrDefault() to the baseQuery but that causes the query to be executed and the OData filter cannot be applied after that.

Answer (score 1):

Use System.Web.Http.SingleResult can make this work

```
SingleResult.Create(queryable)
```

Example:

```
[EnableQuery]
[ODataRoute("Order({orderId})")]
public SingleResult<Order> Get(int orderId)
{
    var result = _myOrders.AsQueryable().Where(mo => mo.ID == orderId);
    return SingleResult.Create(result);
}
```

QueryOptions will apply after result return in controller because of EnableQuery Attribute.

Comment: I am getting the following error message if I use this. Error 1035 The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Http.SingleResult.Create<T>(System.Linq.IQueryable<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Anyway of doing this using ODataQueryOptions as input instead of using the [EnableQuery] attribute?